# Why am I detecting image outside of a defined region?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've used `pyautogui.displayMousePosition()` to determine that the top left corner of where I want to search is **750, 25** and the bottom right is **1200, 125**

Why is this code finding a positive match at **1649, 99**

```
    for image in image_list:
        name = image
        location = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image, region=(750, 25, 1200, 125), confidence=0.9, grayscale=True)
        print(name + " Found at: " + str(location))
```

It looks right based on the [documention](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation the region is defined as a box, so the first 2 parameters are the x,y coordinates of your upper left corner and the next two parameters are the width and the height.

Try with (750,25,1200-750,125-25)